# rendering Unicode glyphs

Tags: java, unicode, rendering

I want to render Unicode glyphs to jpg format. Should I change the font for each Unicode block in my java Code? I tried not to do that, but it did not work. However, changing the font for each block takes a lot of time. Do you know any better way?

Answer (score 3):

> Can I ask which font covers the full
>   Unicode range?

None. Citing [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_typefaces):

> Currently (August, 2008), no single
>   "Unicode font" includes all the
>   characters defined in the present
>   revision of the ISO 10646 (Unicode)
>   standard. In fact, it would be
>   impossible to create such a font in
>   any common font format, as Unicode
>   includes over 100,000 characters,
>   while no widely-used font format
>   supports more than 65,535 glyphs. So
>   while one could make a set of related
>   fonts to cover all of Unicode, a
>   single Unicode font is not possible at
>   this time.

Comment: Thanks Michael, 
Do you or any other person know the answer of my first question?

Thanks,
Shadi.